# Paquete pyodb se conecta a SQLSERVER 2008 y no obtiene datos

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, django

Estoy trabajando con python 3.5.4 y django 1.11.13 instale pyodbc y pyodbc-azure, se conecta pero no hace ninguna cunsulta al sql, aquí les pongo una imagen del código y el debugueo con la respuesta [image: el la cosulta me debe devolver una lista con el nombre e id de las bas de datos], también probe con

```
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_app1',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'db_app2': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'db_app2',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'sa',  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '*****',  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '1433',  # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        'OPTIONS':{ 'driver':'SQL Server Native Client 10.0'},
    }
}
`
```

esto son los campos de una de las tablas despues del inspectdb

```
class FinDocumento(models.Model):
  iddocumento = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 nrodoc = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 estado = models.ForeignKey('FinEstadooperacion', models.DO_NOTHING,   db_column='estado')
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=7950, blank=True, null=True)
idregdoc = models.ForeignKey('FinRegdocum', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idregdoc')
validado = models.BooleanField()
idactividad = models.ForeignKey(FinActividad, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idactividad')
idunidad = models.ForeignKey('GenUnidadcontable', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idunidad')
fechaemision = models.DateTimeField()
fechaprocesam = models.DateTimeField()
crc = models.BigIntegerField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'fin_documento'
```

y tampoco se conecta a db_app2, esta base de datos es para solo hacer consultas ya que esta base de datos puede ser local o externa, probe haciendo el inspectdb y me creó los modelos pero no hace las cosultas tampoco, que me estará faltando

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos la tabla de la BD para saber si es un problema de que no existen los campos en la DB?

Comment: y si le hago el inspectdb para obtener los modelos ,no es mejor ?

Comment: porque de la base de datos db_app2 tiene alrededor de 120 tablas y solo tengo que consultar 10 tablas , que fueron los modelos que deje y cuando hago FinDocumento.objects.filters() esta bacia la lista

Comment: intentastes consultar de la siguiente manera `FinDocumento.objects.using('db_app2').all()` ??

Comment: no de esa forma no he intentado