# Filtrar por campos del mismo modelo

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm

Me hace falta saber como puedo hacer un filtro en un modelo que es de una Factura donde tengo dos campos importe a pagar y otro que es pagado, tengo que hacer un filtro para obtener las facturas que tenga los importes diferentes a los pagados para saber cual de las facturas estan sin pagar.

```
class Facturas(models.Model):
    factura= models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    unidadM = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    importeSD = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    pagadoSD = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    importeEU = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    pagadoEU = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)   
    fechaCreacionFact = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    fechaModifFact = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

He hecho algo pero es Obtener todas las facturas y después un ciclo `for` para comparar el importe con pagado y se demora mucho y se cae la conexión en el navegador por demora de respuesta del servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [expresiones F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). Estas expresiones te permiten referenciar campos del mismo modelo.

En tu caso asumo que tendrías que buscar aquellos cuyos valores en `pagadoSD` y `pagadoEU` sean menores que los valores `importeSD` y `importeEU` respectivamente. En ese caso necesitas también usar [objetos Q()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) para poder hacer un `OR` a nivel de la base de datos:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q
from .models import Facturas


facturas_sin_pagar = Facturas.objects.filter(
    Q(pagadoSD__lt=F('importeSD')) | Q(pagadoEU__lt=F('importeEU'))
)
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es: "obtener aquellas facturas cuyo monto pagado SD o EU sea menor que su respectivo importe".

Comment: me podrias dar una mano con esta pregunta también https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189024/guardar-configuraci%C3%B3n-de-db-para-cargarla-al-iniciar